# How to use __dirname in electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I faced the error that '__dirname is not defined" while using electron.
Does anyone know how to define __dirname?

Comment: Keep in mind that the traditional `__dirname` file location doesn't exist as your dependent modules are packaged into the executable in electron and not present directly in the file system.  I presume electron has a means of packaging other non-code resources into the executable that you can then use or reference.

Comment: do you have any more context about the error?  How are you using `__dirname` when you are seeing the error, and is this when you run the packaged app, when you run in development, or both?

Comment: Greetings :) @ekrall is right, without any information, we can only guess (and that would probably not help you much). The best would be that you create a minimal electron app that only contains the issue and then share the code.

Comment: it is only available in the main process (server part), not in the renderer (web part). if you want to use it in the renderer part, you have to use ipc from main to renderer, to give the renderer this information.